# Decimal Degree data erases itself between edit sessions in QGIS

Tags: field-calculator, geometry, qgis-2, latitude-longitude

I have a shapefile with point data.
I calculate the $x and $y of the points successfully
[image: After lat/lon calculation in decimal degrees]

I save the changes and close the edit session.
Once I reopen the attribute table, the data after the decimal point is gone.
[image: Decimal data is gone]

The field type is Decimal.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precision of the decimal field is 0. Due to limitations in the dbf format and shapefiles, you will have to create a new column. Make the decimal precision in that 5 or more.

Comment: Was easier to answer because you included pics. ciao  : )