# How to export data from sql database in the decimal format in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, sql

Currently I am working with QGIS and fetching data from SQL server and export it in the format of shapefile in QGIS. While importing the data from sql server attribute table showing data with geography having decimal value.

[image]

But after exporting in the format of shapefile data in the attribute table not showing the decimal value. 
[image]

according to article as follows

[decimal degree data erase itself between edit session in qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92162/decimal-degree-data-erases-itself-between-edit-sessions-in-qgis)

in the description they mentioned to add new column and make decimal places precision as 5 or more than that, but attribute table showing for data imported from sql doesn't have  option to make decimal places and add the precision as 5 or more than that. If we check this option in the attribute table of shapefile we can found that. But it not open properly. It got crashed while editing the column. Another question in front of me is how to copy all huge data to new column?

[image]

[image: Attribute editing for sql data table]

I wanted to know:

1. How data got automatically converted in to integer type after exporting it from database
2. Does any new way to add decimal precision for adding new column in sql database imported attribute table and copy all data in the form of decimal places?
3. Does any tools, plug in to convert data type from float to float or any mapping type option for data type available?